# When I add code to IBM Devops Wordpress, the code get reset to default

Tags: php, wordpress, ibm-cloud

In appearance >> Editor >> function.php I have added code to the bottom but the code gets removed when ever I push to Bluemix using CF command line. (cf push)

I was wondering if there was a way to stop it from deleting the code and replacing with default or if there was a special way to add code.

PS: I am using WordPress in bluemix

Comment: I've tried looking trough that but I found nothing on editing themes manually.

Comment: It looks like you have to download your application onto your own machine and make modifications from there. Once you're done you can push the code and it'll work. If you're using someone else's theme then you probably won't be able to make modifications to it since you don't own the source and bluemix is including themes via Composer. You could fork the theme and host it yourself and add your own version to the composer.json file.

Comment: Ok, if I already made changes to the built in customize mode, will that redo my work? Bluemix saves that not sure why though.

Comment: Most of the built-in customize fields are saved to the database and will remain persistent. I'm not too familiar with that feature, and I know other plugins and themes can hook into it so it may vary.

Comment: I think I found a possible plugin to edit the function.php. https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-functions/  Is it possible if you could take a look and just give a guess if it might work

Comment: Probably as it looks like it is saving those inputs in the database.

Comment: Not sure if it will work, but if you use it with bluemix it causes an error with sendgrid

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

if you have a WP version already uploaded to bluemix and you make some changes on the code using WP online tool, if you then make a push from your local copy your changes will be overwritten by your local copy, which is not updated with the last changes

If you make some changes online on your bluemix WP instance, you don't need to make cf push then.